# Errors prevented startup in meteor JS

Tags: meteor

I run the following command for camera package.

```
meteor add mdg:camera
```

The following issue is getting triggered when I run `meteor run` in ubuntu terminal.

```
Errors prevented startup:                  

   While building for web.browser:
   error: no plugin found for camera.less in mdg:camera; a plugin for *.less was active when it was published but none is now

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

My meteor version is 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Add one of the many available less packages to your application. For example:

```
meteor add less
```

Answer (score 0):

remove both less and mdg:camera from package.json
then after meteor as removed and restarted app add 
less@2.6.5
mdg:camera@1.4.1

solves the issue

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade to 1.3.2.4
I just had the same problem, started working after downgrade.